# How can I create a kind of thread on arduino board?

Tags: c, multithreading, gps, arduino

I would like to receive information from a GPS receiver every second, but from sensors - every half second...

I took the code of tinyGPS and added it sensors code:

```
#include <TinyGPS.h>

const int RightPin = A0;
const int FrontPin = A1;
const int LeftPin = A2;
int RightVal = 0;
int FrontVal = 0;
int LeftVal = 0;

TinyGPS gps;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);   //GPS DATA
  Serial1.begin(9600); //GPS
  Serial2.begin(9600); //BLUETOOTH

}

void loop() {
  RightVal = analogRead(RightPin);
  FrontVal = analogRead(FrontPin);
  LeftVal = analogRead(LeftPin);
  Serial1.print(RightVal);
  Serial1.print(", ");
  Serial1.print(FrontVal);
  Serial1.print(", ");
  Serial1.println(LeftVal);

  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();

  // Every second we print an update
  while (millis() - start < 1000)
  {
    if (feedgps())
      newdata = true;
  }
  gpsdump(gps);
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can achieve this by using interrupts. You can use a timer to generate an interrupt every 0.5 seconds and just read your sensors every time (and the GPS every two).

I haven't done this in arduino but in c with AVR microcontrollers. There must be a lot of documentation online.

from [this link](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1) you can read:

```
attachInterrupt(function, period)
Calls a function at the specified interval in microseconds. Be careful about trying to execute too complicated of an interrupt at too high of a frequency, or the CPU may never enter the main loop and your program will 'lock up'. Note that you can optionally set the period with this function if you include a value in microseconds as the last parameter when you call it.
```